# Задача от Yandex

Tags: javascript, криптография

Участвовал в YandexCup. Алгоритм тестов от этой компании не принимал моё решение к их задаче.

Вот сама задача.

Задача

Вам нужно написать функцию в виде CommonJS модуля, которая на вход принимает массив чисел (примитив Number) и возвращает строку.

Сигнатура

```
function(numbers: Number[]): string
Пример оформления задачи
```

```
module.exports = function(numbers) {
  // code
};
```

Условия:

- Ваше устройство вывода не исправно и умеет выводить только цифры, латинские буквы, пробел и символ нижнего подчеркивания;
- Нельзя использовать кавычки (литеральные и шаблонные строки) – ', ", ` ;
- Нельзя использовать и создавать объекты String и Symbol;
- Функция на вход принимает массив чисел вида [17,40,47,47,50,62,34,36,12,56,51,62,2,0,2,2];
- Функция должна возвращать сообщение одной последовательностью символов;
- Неизвестные символы программа должна заменять на _

Решение оформлено в виде CommonJS модуля;

Алфавит:

Сообщения, которые удалось расшифровать. Пока полный алфавит не известен.

```
[14,12,22,10,28,38,53,44,51,55,62,2,0,1,5] === 'ECMAScript 2015'
```

Примеры:
Пример 1

```
const numbers = [17,40,47,47,50,62,34,36,12,56,51,62,2,0,2,2];
// Hello YaCup 2022
```

Пример 2

```
const numbers = [17,40,47,47,50,62,32,50,53,47,39,-1];

// Hello World_
```

Вот моё решение:

Из условия понятно, что алфавит для расшифровки выглядит таким образом.

```
 const alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz _'
```

Мой код:

```
module.exports=function(numbers){
    return numbers.map((a)=>{
        if(a>=63||a<0){
            return String.fromCharCode(95)
        }
        if(a===62){
            return String.fromCharCode(32)
        }
        if(a<=9){
            return a
        }
        if(a<=35){
            return String.fromCharCode(a+55)
        }
        return String.fromCharCode(a+61)
    }).join([])   
}
```

Я предполагаю, что из-за `String.fromCharCode` моё решение не принимало. Интересно посмотреть на другие решения. Каким образом можно ещё получить символы без использования кавычек?

Comment: Классная задача!

Comment: Стоит дать вопросу нормальное название отражающее его суть

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть куча способов:

```js
console.log(/That's not a string/.source)
console.log((12).toString(36).toUpperCase())
console.log((55-26).toString(36))
console.log(Object.keys({Q:1,_:1,A:1}).join([]))
console.log(0 + ({}+[])[7] + 1)
```

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` - не является ли это нарушением условия "Нельзя использовать и создавать объекты String и Symbol"?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, не является. У меня такое решение проходило почти все тесты. Почти - потому что я не учёл кое-что другое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по сути я мог весь алфавит поместить в регулярное выражение, получить его из свойство source и обращаться к каждому символу по индексу?

Comment: @HTOHOT, одно из возможных решений.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать так

```js
module.exports = function(numbers) {
  const alphabet = /0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz _/
  return numbers.map((a) => {
    return alphabet.source[a] ? alphabet.source[a] : alphabet.source[63]



  }).join([])
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]